# Retrieve data to put as a parameter when logging in

Tags: angularjs

**EDIT:**
Including more code because I'm having a hard time implementing your solution.

```
        [...]
        $scope.loginForm.loading = false;
        $scope.submitLoginForm = function() {
        $scope.loginForm.loading = true;

        $http
            .put('/login', {
                email: $scope.loginForm.login,
                username: $scope.loginForm.login,
                password: $scope.loginForm.password,
                _csrf: `here goes the token`
            })
            .then(function onSuccess() {
                window.location = '/myPage';
                toastr.success('You are in!', 'Success', { closeButton: true });
            })
            .catch(function onError(sailsResponse) {
                // if (sailsResponse.status === 403) {
                //   // toastr.error('Removed', 'Error', {
                //   //   closeButton: true
                //   // });
                //   window.location = '/restore';
                //   return;
                // }

                // Handle known error type(s).
                // Invalid username / password combination.
                if (sailsResponse.status === 400 || 404) {
                    // $scope.loginForm.topLevelErrorMessage = 'Invalid email/password combination.';
                    //
                    toastr.error(
                        'Invalid email or username/password combination.',
                        'Error',
                        {
                            closeButton: true
                        }
                    );
                    return;
                }

                toastr.error(
                    'An unexpected error occurred, please try again.',
                    'Error',
                    {
                        closeButton: true
                    }
                );
                return;
            })
            .finally(function eitherWay() {
                $scope.loginForm.loading = false;
            });
    };
[...]
```

---

```
[...]
$scope.submitLoginForm = function() {
    $http
        .put('/login', {
            email: $scope.loginForm.login,
            username: $scope.loginForm.login,
            password: $scope.loginForm.password,
            _csrf: `I need the data here`
        })
[...]
```

How do I retrieve the `_csrf` paramether, reachable through a GET in `/csrfToken`, at the exact time the request is being send?

Comment: "And incluing some random text because SO complaints"?  What are you talking about?  If SO is giving you an error when you create or edit a post, you should follow it's instructions, not "paste some random text to get around it"....

Comment: I see. So this time I went against the rules, but the next time will be ok to summarize what has been said in the comments rather than put random text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the exact time but you can get the csrf_token just before you call '/login'.

```js
$scope.submitLoginForm = function() {
    $http.get('/csrfToken')
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        var csrf = response.data._csrf;
        $http.put('/login', {
            email: $scope.loginForm.login,
            username: $scope.loginForm.login,
            password: $scope.loginForm.password,
            _csrf: csrf
        });
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(response.statusText);
    });
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question, when you have time please have a look

Comment: How do you get the _csrf parameter from /csrfToken? Do you need to pass any more parameters to this REST endpoint? What is logged in the console when you run $http.get('/csrfToken').then(function successCallback(response) {console.log(response);});

Comment: Notice how I am getting the "csrf" first from GET "/csrfToken" before I make a PUT request to "/login".

Comment: I have edited my answer to match your question. Can you add console.log(response) after line 3 to see what is the response you get?

Comment: Got a 200! Object { data: Object, status: 200, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" } but is it normal that it doesn't keep the login active? Could it be for the missing redirect? Even if it shouldn't be for that reason, I ask to be sure

Comment: Don't you need to get the csrf first before you log in? 200 means the request is ok. I also changed my answer to use var csrf=response.data._csrf; (previously missing the underscore) . You should console.log(response.data) to see what the response payload is. I think preciously the missing underscore is causing an issue.

Comment: IT WORKS! I missed the underscore too on the 2nd paste but now it works! Thank you very much! Now I'll try to mix the original code with your solution and it'll be all fine, thank you again